# Would it be possible to reconstruct 3d trajectory of ball projectile using only monocular video

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, geometry

Assume ball location on the image frame in each timestamp is given.

Would it be possible to reconstruct the ball's 3d trajectory in the camera's coordinate frame?

The ball should be able to described using constant acceleration model, as it only subject to gravity and initial throwing force

Edit: I am hoping if someone could points out whether it be possible to deduce the unobservable perpendicular motion, after some flying time

Comment: Do you know the size of the image of the ball in each timestamp? Do you know the size of the ball?

Comment: Yes, but I just consider the ball as a ball in space

Comment: OK so no air drag, as implied by the constant acceleration model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what Olli implies: Using a lens distortion matrix if necessary, the center of the ball in the picture gives you an elevation and azimuth of your ball relative to the focal point of your camera. The size of the ball image gives you distance.

That's a point in 3D space.

From there, it's really only a manner of grammar school level math to estimate the four (or only three – do you know the mass of the planet you're on?) unknowns in your problem (three components of initial velocity, and maybe magnitude of gravity), at least without considerations for measurement error from multiple observations of the ball.

If you need to take measurement error (finite shutter speed, finite frame rate, finite camera resolution, imperfect estimation of position from picture) into account, well, feels like the classical problem where you'd throw a Kalman at it and be done.

In fact, I think [this](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/) nice little article "*How a Kalman filter works, in pictures*" has an explanation that nearly completely describes a solution for your specific problem.

Comment: I don't have the camera intrinsic not the distortion parameters. Neither is the size of the ball is reliable. all I have is the centre of mass of the ball in every frame.

Comment: Well, you'll need some way to calibrate that camera. But that's usually easy to do - openCV comes with functions for that.

Comment: Regarding the size of the ball: you explicitly said you know it in the comments to your question.